Python Returns Different File Size than OS Property
I am trying to get the size of a a file called fGDB.gdb using python. but while the Windows Property shows the size of file as 146 KB (150,399 bytes)

Using this code
import os

gdb = r"C:\Users\...\....\fGDB.gdb"
file_size = os.path.getsize(gdb)
print("File Size is :", file_size, "bytes")

return this:
File Size is : 12288 bytes
Can someone please let me know why the size are different and how I can get the exact number which showing on OS Property window by Python too?

Are you sure the file isn't being modified while you're doing this?

Yes Barmar, I am sure it is not been touched or modified

I wonder if it has something to do with being a "file folder" rather than an ordinary file.

You are right! a .gdb  is a container of GIS binary files

Could you be pulling the chached file maybe?
